# Wordpress Two Steps Autoresponders Form Submition

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7, auto-responder

Need some wordpress gurus insight here!

Basically, I've a plugin call Contact Form 7 to display a form on my site.

May I know how can I achieve these steps :-

1. User click submit, they will auto-receive a mail containing activation link.
2. User click the activation link, they will auto-receive another email to containing some text to ask them to upload a picture.
3. On my end, I'll only receive the lead only when the user completing the 2nd step.

Is it possible to do it with wordpress plugins? Or I need some external api or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can get more information to set up the points for Autoresponders Form Submission

**Go Through the link -** https://www.formget.com/send-copy-of-message-to-form-submitter-use-auto-responder/